# submit a remote form_tag in rails 3 using javascript but submits as html

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a form_tag in rails 3 as follows and I want to submit this form using ajax instead of html via javascript. When I click the submit button it does submit as javascript

```
- form_tag({:controller => "checkin", :action => "main_page"}, :remote => true, :method => :get, :id => "get_location_form" ) do
  Latitude:
  = text_field_tag 'latitude_field', '', :size => 10, :class => 'submittable'
  Longitude:
  = text_field_tag 'longitude_field', '', :size => 10, :class => 'submittable'
  = submit_tag "Send Info"
```

Also I am using jQuery so I have these functions in my application.js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#get_location_form").submitWithAjax();
});

jQuery.fn.submitWithAjax = function() {
  this.submit(function() {
    $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  });
  return this;
};
```

Why is it that when I press the button manually, It sends a javascript request but when I use the form.submit() in javascript to submit the form, it receives it as a HTML request.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can see the jquery_ujs script to understand how it does :

https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js

I think you need update the RequestHeader like do here : https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js#L137

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('accept', '*/*;q=0.5, ' + settings.accepts.script);
```

Comment: where would I update my RequestHeader? I checked in my jquery_ujs and it is there but I am not sure where and how I would update it. Im a bit of a newbie with this, thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 0):

solved: just use `$("#referenceSubmit").trigger("click");` where referenceSubmit is the id of the submit button